# How to control response in interceptor

Tags: angularjs, rest

Using an interceptor in Angularjs, I have a question. I need to control status 403, but in my app when the API returns a 403 the app makes a logout. The API will return a 403 in a special case. I don't want that the interceptor makes the logout and I don't know when I can find some attribute that the API returns.

```
responseError: function(rejection) {

    if (rejection.status === 0) {
      //some stuff
    }
    else if (rejection.status === 401 || rejection.status === 403){
      $injector.get("Service").logout();
    }
```

Can I get the attributes the API returns in the rejection object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look `rejection` object in console, you will see it returns data property which is API response

```
responseError: function(rejection) {

    console.log(rejection.data) //API response data

    if (rejection.status === 0) {
      //some stuff
    }
    else if (rejection.status === 401 || rejection.status === 403){
      $injector.get("Service").logout();
    }
```

Comment: If I send a POST to /api/method/108 and I get an error. Can I get the 108 from the error message? Or I have to saved it by myself?

Comment: yes you can get request data as `rejection.config.data` and request url `rejection.config.url`